# What output video format for Kazam requires less cpu power?

Tags: video-capture, screen-casting

Please tell me what is the appropriate StackExchange site to post this question if it doesn't fit here.

I use Kazam to capture my videoconferences. It gets too CPU-demanding but the program is awesome so it doesn't crash but drop frames instead, so that the final video may have 1 frame per second in the most difficult moments but with an uninterrupted sound and full correct images.

Which one of these output formats for the video will be less demanding for the program, so that the frame rate does not drop to such low values? I don't mind a big file size, I can compress the video later. Here are the options:

VP8 in webm container,

H.264 in MP4,

RAW video in AVI,

HUFFYUV (no darn idea what this is) in AVI,

Lossless JPEG in AVI.

Answer (score 1):

VP8 and H.264 should essentially be the same demand due to them being similar.

RAW is well, RAW, each specific pixel data, with no methods of reducing file space, this can cause very large file sizes, but is in theory the least intensive as long as your hard drive can record fast enough.

HUFFYUV is basically the same as RAW, however it uses some methods to reduce file size. Depending on the footage it can be about half the size, or even up to 1/10th the size of RAW.

Lossless JPEG, I believe is similar to HUFFYUV, however I don't personally use either of these lossless codecs.

I don't know if Kazam allows you to use custom codecs, but if it does, I highly recommend using the Lagarith Lossless Codec. It's what I personally use, and it has some basic GPU support, very nice file sizes without any loss in quality, and doesn't require any tinkering which some lossless codecs do.